# having trouble to integrate search results with pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I got the pagination controls and my search results shows 5 results fine. but when I click the second page, all of the search results go away. even though for what I searched, there is more than 5 results in the database. if you would please see the update code in just a second. here is my email bud just in case: raminrahim [at] hotmail [dot] com Please. thanks.

```
<?php 
    $paginationCTRLS = '';
    $textline1 = '';
    $textline2 = '';
    $list = '';
    if (isset($_GET['search_item'])) {
        $search_item = $_GET['search_item'];
        if (!empty($search_item)) {
            if (strlen($search_item)>=3) {
              // This query is just to get total count of rows
              $query= "SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM items";  // $sql
              $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);  // $query
              $query_row = mysqli_fetch_row($query_run);     // $row
              // $rows: here we have the total row count
              $rows = $query_row[0]; // pgRows = row[]
              // This is the number of results we want displayed per page
              $page_rows = 5;
              // This tells us the page number of our last page
              $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
              // This makes sure last cannot be less than 1.
              if ($last < 1)
                    {
                        $last = 1;
                    }
              // Establish the $pagenum variables
              $pagenum = 1;
              // Get pagenum from URL vars if it present, else it is = 1
              if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
                $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
                    }
              if ($pagenum < 1) {
                    $pagenum = 1;
              } else if ($pagenum > $last) {
                            $pagenum = $last;
              }
              $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
             $query = "SELECT `item_id`, `featured_Items` FROM `items` WHERE
                     `featured_Items` LIKE   
                     '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_item)."%' $limit";
             $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
             $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
             if ($query_num_rows>=1) 
                 {
                   echo $query_num_rows. ' results found:<br>' . '<br>';
                   while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) 
                       {
                        echo $query_row['featured_Items'].'<br>' . '<hr>';
                       }
                  }
                  else
                    { 
                       echo 'No result found' . '<hr>';
                    } 
                } else {
                echo 'Not enough keywords to predict your search' . '<hr>';
                }
            }
    $textline1 = "Result:" .  '(<b>$rows</br>)';
    $textline2 = "Page <b>" . '$pagenum' . "</b> of <b>" . '$last' . "</b>";
    if ($last != 1){
       if ($pagenum > 1) {
         $previous = $pagenum - 1;
         $paginationCTRLS .= '<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Back</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';

    for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
         if($i>0){

                $paginationCTRLS .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search_item='.$search_item.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
               }
        }   
    }
    $paginationCTRLS .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';

        for ($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++) {
                $paginationCTRLS .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search_item='.$search_item.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
             if($i >= $pagenum+4) {
                    break;
                }
         }
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
            $next = $pagenum +1;
            $paginationCTRLS .= '&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';

        }
    }
    $list = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row["item_id"];
    $availablesITEMS = $row["featured_Items"];
    $list .= '<p><a href="boxbar.php?id='.$id.'">'.$availablesITEMS.'</a><br>.</p>';
    }   
  }      
    echo $list . '<br/>'; 
    echo $paginationCTRLS . '<br/>';

?>
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite your code with more consistent indentation? Right now it is very hard to follow. Who knows, you might even find the bug in the process.

Comment: sure please hang on for one sec I will edit it now.

Comment: Hi Anders can you read it better now? please let me know if more edits needed.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Some things I noticed: 1. When you check how many items there are(`SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM items`), you don't use the where clause. 2. When you get the rows from the database, you use `LIMIT 5` even though you want to display 10 posts at a time, and you do not take what page you´re on into account. 3. You never actually echo `$paginationCTRLS`.

Comment: thanks Andres can you please and I mean please stick around for a sec?

Comment: Thanks for bringing to my attention about the paginationCTRLS. but now I get this error when I echo it. even though I have said paginationCTRLS = ''; somewhere in my code Undefined variable: paginationCTRLS

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: Right now the description of the problem in your question does not match the actual problem you are having. Please fix that. Note that if you are at a low page number you will get links to negative pages because of the way the for loop is written (`($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++)`). Does the problem occur only when you click on negative links? Could you give me the value of `$limit`?

Comment: Woops, missed the `if(i>0)`. Could you give me the value of `$limit`?

Comment: Is the variable empty?

Comment: `$limit`. Saw your post before the edit, that's why I asked. Could you give me the actual value, not the code? Do an `echo $limit;` And give me the value both on the first and the second page, plus how many rows it found (`$query_num_rows`)

Comment: $page_rows = 5; $pagenum = 1; $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

Comment: this is what I got: LIMIT 0,5 on the screen

Comment: That is on the first page, right? Then on the second page? And how many rows in the result - `$query_num_rows`?

Comment: yes bud and it shows up right down below the pagination navigation numbers and also when I do a search. on the second page nothing shows up at all. no pagination, no results. nothing.

Comment: What does it say on the second page? And how many rows in the result?

Comment: just nothing at all bud. I mean my results don't show up and even that echo limit thing doesn't show up at all. oh and on the second page the result set should be 1 more result.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your query to be able to accept an start point.
Like this:

```
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Where the first number corresponds to the starting row your results are going to be obtained from, and the second number equals the amount of results you're going to get from that point on.
So in the sense of your code you'd have to set it up as:

```
$query = "SELECT `item_id`, `featured_Items` FROM `items` WHERE
                     `featured_Items` LIKE   
                     '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_item)."%' 
                      LIMIT ".($pagenum-1)*5.",5";
```

Let me know if that clears up your doubt.

Edit:

As for enabling pagination through your means, simply change the method in your form to be a GET statement.

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="get">
```

Then from your code you can use the

```
$_GET['search_item']
```

method instead of POST. This in turn enables you to use those variables on your anchor tags for your pagination.

```
$paginationCTRLS .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search_item='.$search_item.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';`
```

Edit2:
You have this piece of code:

```
for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
         if($i>0){
                $paginationCTRLS .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search_item='.$search_item.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
         }
}
```

This will always at any point output the same number of pages, which is 5.

Now what you need is something that outputs only the pagination that you really need. So for example setting up this variable:

```
$pages = ceil($row/$page_rows);
```

Gives you your total amount of pages, then you can iterate to it:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++){
             if($i>0){
                    $paginationCTRLS .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search_item='.$search_item.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
             }
    }
```

Comment: I would check the quotation marks on your paginationCTRLS declarations right inside the for loops ;)

Comment: @Ramin Rahimi, just a question but, on the second page, how are you passing on the POST value? I can't seem to see it on your code. And unless this is present, nothing will happen as it won't even get past the first "if" statement.

Comment: right right. so do you know how can I fix that bud? because your right I don't think I am passing the post value.

Comment: here is what i did which it didn't work I replaced $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] with $_POST['search_item'] because seach_item is what the user searches and is the results of the search basically right. but when I did this and clicked on the second page, it couldn't find the page.

Comment: Well I would assume you're doing this with an input text field, and have that form's method set as post in order to send your search values. Just change that method to get, use a $_GET['search_item'] call instead of the post one, and add your search_item to the anchor tags as the first argument, your page as the second. If you want I can edit my post to include this a little better.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it Orlando you're the men. as I am a confused dump ass. thank you.

Comment: @RaminRahimi check the edit to my post, let me know how it all works out bud.

Comment: Duuuuddddeeee.  I LOVE YOUUUUU. it worked.  but one last thing if you could please help out. it works but now I see extra pages like 12345 but my search result only has 6 results which is limited to 5 per page. can you please help me with that and this thread is solved. actually one last thing also when I click back button everything disappears.

Comment: @RaminRahimi Sure, it seems you're setting "for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++)" which is always going to create 4 iterations of your anchors. I believe the right code for this is the one you have on the for loop right below that one.

Comment: I just want to say thank you so much bud. But right now the existing problems are two and I am done: first, my back and next buttons both don't work and second I have 5 pages listed even though what I search for, only has 2 pages of results. I am going to update my code for your convenience.

Comment: I'm gonna go by parts here, first i'm looking at your next and back buttons: Don't forget to add the search_item value in your url, look into my post for an example.

Comment: Oh My God. Your the smartest dude I ever seen. the back and next button problem Fixed. Hhahaaa. Thank you. Just one last thing bud. and that is the extra pagination links. I promise I will leave you alone after this.

Comment: sorry bro that actually didn't work because what that does is to duplicate the pagination numbers.

Comment: so basically where you have like $pages in the loop mine I put $last because thats the variable for ceil function: $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $last; $i++)

Comment: Alright so the previous for loop is for what precisely? the one I commented about on my post

Comment: Try commenting that out and tell me what happens.

Comment: so what happens if Ignore this loop, the previous page disappears when you click next and reappears when you click back but the extra pages are still there.

Comment: Hey bud I understand this is my problem but unfortunately, I have to leave the house to go to school. I Seriously thank you for all you have done. if you could and if you want to, I would greatly and greatly appreciate it if you can send me a email. And I really and greatly am sorry that I have to leave to go to school and I know you don't have to do this but I appreciate it if you can help me on this. my email is raminrahim[at]hotmail[dot]com

Again you're the greatest. Thank you again.